# Как правильно вставлять записи из DataTable в MS SQL Server не нарушая связи?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

Есть таблицы на SQL Server, между которыми есть связь:

```
Table1: (ID Identity INT, FileName nvarchar(255))

Table2: (ID Identity INT, ParentId INT(Внешний ключ к Table1) ...)
```

Программа должна на стороне клиента генерировать 2 пустых DataTable с новыми записями и отправлять их на сервер => осуществлять вставки в эти таблицы на сервере.

Как это сделать, чтобы не возникли проблемы со связями, ведь заранее я не знаю какие `IDENTITY` будут сгенерированы сервером.

Также в эти таблицы (на сервере) могут вставлять данные другие пользователи. Логика при мультипользовании поменяется или можно абстрагироваться от этого?

Comment: Вставить в БД данные первой таблицы. Получить обратно сгенерированные ID. Вставить в БД данные второй таблицы уже с этими ID.

Comment: Можно решить проблему кардинально: перейти на GUID'ы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, структуру таблицы трогать нельзя. А можно пример кода по первому вашему комментарию? Никогда не слал на сервер таблицы с отношениями...

Comment: Если источники данных в приложении созданы через дизайнер датасетов в VS, то код обновления мог сгенерироваться автоматически, с учетом внешних ключей. А так, см. [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/33y2221y(v=vs.110).aspx) и [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0.aspx).

Comment: Подробно проблемы вставки/обновления данных с автосгенерироваными ID описаны в книге "Программирование ADO.NET 2.0" Дэвида Сеппы.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а для изучения всех тонкостей ADO.NET эта книга по прежнему актуальна? Вроде, она довольна старая.

Comment: Сама технология ADO.NET с тех пор не менялась. Думаю, более новых книг на русском нет. Просто сейчас мало кто использует сырой ADO.NET, больше разные ORM типа EF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как это сделать, чтобы не возникли проблемы со связями, ведь заранее
>   я не знаю какие будут IDENTITY сгенерированы сервером.

Это можно сделать следующим образом.

Предположим на клиентской стороне в C# коде у нас есть таблицы

```cs
var table1 = new DataTable("Table1");
table1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
table1.Columns.Add("FileName", typeof(string));

var table2 = new DataTable("Table2");
table2.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
table2.Columns.Add("ParentID", typeof(int));
table2.Columns.Add(...);
```

которые мы наполняем какими-то данными. Если данные всегда новые и на стороне SqlServer подлежат безусловной вставке, то ID генерируем любые. Это будут "временные" ID.

Пересылаем данные `table1` и `table2` каким-либо образом на сервер (через табличные параметры, с помощью SqlBulkCopy во временные таблицы, или каким-либо иным образом). Предположим, что передали данные во временные таблицы `#table1` и `#table2`.

На стороне SqlServer для вставки данных в первую таблицу используем `MERGE` с предложением `OUTPUT`, что позволит сопоставить назначенные нами временные ID с фактическими. Затем вставляем данные во вторую таблицу, используя это сопоставление:

```sql
create table #map1 (TmpID int, ActualID int, primary key (TmpID));

merge into Table1 t
using #table1 s
on 1 = 0
when not matched then
    insert (FileName)
    values (s.FileName)
output s.ID, inserted.ID into #map1 (TmpID, ActualID);

insert into Table2 (ParentID, ...)
select m1.ActualID, ...
from #table2 t2
    left join #map1 m1 on m1.TmpID = t2.ParentID;

drop table #map1;
```

> Так же в эти таблицы (на сервере) могут вставлять данные другие
>   пользователи. Логика при мультипользовании поменяется или можно
>   абстрагироваться от этого?

При мультипользовании никаких коррекций не потребуется.

Comment: Хм... Что-то я совсем забыл про INSERTED. Тогда, наверное, и без Merge тоже самое сделать можно. А обязательно все сливать во временные таблицы? Нельзя заталкивать все в Table1, затем получить актуальные ID для DataTable, обновить их в DataTable2 и вставить записи в Table2?

Comment: @iluxa1810, _"без Merge"_ - имеется ввиду с помощью `insert`? Нет, с insert то же самое не получится, insert не позволит направить `s.ID` в output. Только merge позволяет одновременно с inserted.* направлять в output данные из источника.

Comment: @iluxa1810, _"Нельзя заталкивать все в Table1, затем получить актуальные ID для DataTable, обновить их в DataTable2 и вставить записи в Table2?"_ наверное можно. Это несколько другой архитектурный подход. Возможно он может быть удобнее в каких-то случаях. Здесь клиент с сервером договариваются о формате данных (#table, @ table, xml или ещё что-то). Клиент отправляет данные на сервер, сервер их импортирует (в отдельной ХП, к примеру). При двухступенчатом импорте клиент получается вовлечённым в процесс сильнее.